# How to solve the error "Type provided must be an Enum. Parameter name: enumType"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, enums, formcollection, paysimple

So I've been using the Pay Simple SDK. I'm getting this error. Does anyone know how to solve this?

```
var customerPayment = new NewCustomerPayment<CreditCard>
```

So my model is in the Pay Simple SDK. This is for Payment Transaction.

Controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<ActionResult> Create(FormCollection formCollection) {
    string username = "jnjk";
    string apiKey = "khkh";
    string baseUrl = "https://sandbox-api.paysimple.com";
    var settings = new PaySimpleSdk.Models.PaySimpleSettings(apiKey, username, baseUrl);

    var paymentService = new PaymentService(settings);

    var customerPayment = new NewCustomerPayment<CreditCard>()
    {

        Customer = new Customer
        {
            FirstName = formCollection["FirstName"],
            LastName = formCollection["LastName"],
            BillingAddress = (Address)Enum.Parse(typeof(Address), formCollection["BillingAddress"])
        },

        Account = new CreditCard
        {
            CreditCardNumber = formCollection["CreditCardNumber"],
            ExpirationDate = formCollection["ExpirationDate"],
            Issuer = (Issuer)Enum.Parse(typeof(Issuer), formCollection["Issuer"])
        },

        Payment = new Payment
        {  
            Amount = int.Parse(formCollection["Amount"]),
            Cvv = formCollection["Ccv"]
        }

    };

    var newCustomerPayment = await paymentService.CreateNewCustomerPaymentAsync(customerPayment);

    return View();
}
```

Model from sdk

This is The Billing Address in the Customer Model..

```
  public Address BillingAddress { get; set; }
```

This is for Address

```
  public class Address : IValidatable
  {
    public Address();
    public string City { get; set; }
    public CountryCode? Country { get; set; }
    public StateCode? StateCode { get; set; }
    public string StreetAddress1 { get; set; }
    public string StreetAddress2 { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure `Address` and `Issuer` are enums? They sound like classes to me. [`Enum.Parse(Type enumType, string value)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559(v=vs.110).aspx) throws an exception if `enumType` is not an enum-type.

Comment: public enum Issuer
    {
        Visa = 12,
        Master = 13,
        Amex = 14,
        Discover = 15
    }

Comment: So I think the address is not enum,

Comment: @SylzzHeartnet, that's probably the case then.

Comment: what would be the proper way of calling it??

Comment: That indeed doesn't look like an enum. You could try `BillingAddress =  formCollection["BillingAddress"]` and making `BillingAddress` of type `Address`.

Comment: I already tried that but having an error in this because it's not a string, because address have 6 other classes(street1,street2,country,state,city and zip)

Comment: @SylzzHeartnet, that's why you should change the type of `BillingAddress` to `Address`.

Comment: I can't change it, because the model is from PaySimple SDK, another way to solve this ??

Comment: @SylzzHeartnet, instead of asking it here, you should open this as a new question (if you're really stuck). Also don't forget to mark this as the correct answer if it helped you :)

Comment: What do you think is the possible question for this?? I don't know what type is that address? string,int,enum or?? I can't produce a question  :D

Comment: @SylzzHeartnet I don't know what the field represents so I can't help you. Maybe it requires all fields of `Address` concatenated in a `String`. You should read the official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code your *raw* address data lives in a [`FormCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.formcollection), which is some form of a `NameValueCollection`. So you would need to know what the contents of `formCollection["BillingAddress"]` looks like.

If this is some form of json or map, then you can parse it with a Json parser or via reflection and fill your `Address` class.

Note: it would be helpful, if you showed us, what the value of this key looks like, in case this does not answer your question.

Comment: I will add it on the answer

Comment: I already edit the answe, there the value in the Billing Address

Answer (score 0):

I already solved my problem by doing this...

```
 BillingAddress =
    {
     StreetAddress1 = formCollection["StreetAddress1"],
     StreetAddress2 = formCollection["StreetAddress2"],
     City = formCollection["City"],
     StateCode = (StateCode)Enum.Parse(typeof(StateCode), formCollection["StateCode"]),
     Country = (CountryCode)Enum.Parse(typeof(CountryCode), formCollection["Country"]),
     ZipCode = formCollection["ZipCode"]
    }
```